# Coredata and Mogenerator, coredata flag concurrency issues EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I added the Core Data concurrency flag to my project. I'm also using Mogenerator. When I try to get a variables values w/ mogens getters it hits a breakpoint. Here's my function:

```
- (BOOL) existsOnServer{
    id someID = self.id; // breakpoint hit here
    return (!someID || someID == (id)[NSNull null])?NO:YES;
}
```

This function exists in my main custom object class that everything inherits from. Does anyone know why this could be throwing this error?

Comment: What thread are you accessing `self.id` from and what is your CoreData threading policy?

Comment: your comment helped me come to the below answer so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was calling the above method inside a block of code that was executed on a thread different than main, which is where I assume 'self' was created.

I found out that I can use a managed object contexts `managedObjectContext` parameter. This is the context the object was created with and will only be nil if the context no longer exists. By using perform block on this context I can get the data I need from the object.